# How to get the particular div of a table?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, row

I have a table as below which has 9 rows. From second row onwards the format of the row content is same.

My requirement is I have to iterate through second row to last row and in each row I should be able to set the text for 3rd div (`<div class="homeLeftPaneText">want to set the text here </div>`)

```
<table id="__table1-table" >
   <tbody>
      <tr role="row" >
         <th aria-owns="__column1" aria-labelledby="__column1" style=""></th>
     </tr>

      <tr id="__table1-rows-row0" class="">
         <td id="__table1-rows-row0-col0" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="__table1-ariadesc __column1 __html1-col0-row0" >
            <div >
               <div class="homeLeftPaneRow" data-sap-ui-preserve="__html1-col0-row0" id="__html1-col0-row0">
                  <div class="homeLeftPaneIcon homeLeftPaneStartIcon"> </div>
                  <div class="homeLeftPaneText"> Getting Started</div>
                  <div class="homeLeftPaneText">want to set the text here </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>

    <tr >
        //same format as  in __table1-rows-row0
    </tr>

   <tr id="__table1-rows-row4" >

   </tr>
   <tr id="__table1-rows-row4" >
          //same format as  in __table1-rows-row0            
   </tr>
   <tr id="__table1-rows-row4" >
          //same format as  in __table1-rows-row0            
   </tr>

    <tr id="__table1-rows-row4" >
          //same format as  in __table1-rows-row0            
   </tr>

    <tr id="__table1-rows-row4" >
          //same format as  in __table1-rows-row0            
   </tr>

    <tr id="__table1-rows-row4" >
          //same format as  in __table1-rows-row0            
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot have double id's! you have the same id for many rows. So you want to set the text with the div tags or just the text?

Comment: use classes like class="__table1-rows-row4" and not ids

Answer (score 2):

One problem here is that no two DOM elements should have the same id. Use a class instead.

What you want to do is, after assigning the proper class to all those table rows, use jQuery to grab every instance of the class, find the div you want (you need to assign that set of divs a unique class), then modify it.

So it would look something like

```
$(".__table1-rows-row4").find(".modifythis").html("new text here");
```

after you attach the appropriate class to the divs you need to change

Answer (score 0):

If you're only modifying that div and the contents of all of those divs will be the same, you could just add a class to that div such as "setTextHere" and then modify the text as:

```
$(".setTextHere").html("New Text");
```

If the text is is different for each of these third divs, then you will have to find the respective parent element. In this example N is the number of row.

```
$("#__table1-rows-rowN").find(".setTextHere").html("Text for Row N");
```